# how to go-to-definition on require statement in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, visual-studio-code

Is `go to definition` enabled on `require` statements in VSCode?

```
(1) var a = require('a');
(2) var b = a;
```

If I do `go to definition` (f12) on line 2 on (a) it goes to line 1 as expected. When trying `go to definition` on the require line (line 1) it does nothing.

Is `go to definition` supported on require statements in vscode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Node modules resolve plugin for VSCode](https://github.com/naumovs/vscode-ext-node-module-resolve). It provides definitions for commonjs requires in your code for quick navigation. Works with commonjs modules and import module system.

Comment: Please add context to your link in the way of a code sample. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Finally! Been looking for an extension like this!

Answer (score 0):

I use requireJS and [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jrieken.fuzzy-definitions) extension worked for me perfectly.